# jquery with jsf

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem integrating JQuery with JSF.

I use Spin. and I have in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js"></script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $.spin.imageBasePath = '../images/spin1/';
      $('#spin1').spin();
      $('#spin2').spin();
      $('#spin3').spin();
    }
```

When I invoke the page for the first time, the "spin" is being added to components.

The problem is that I have  as well, and once I invoke it and update part of the page (where I have the spinners) - it doesn't function anymore. It seems that Jquery is being invoked only on page read and once refreshing a part of it - i would execute it anymore.

I tried to use `h:commandButton` with `f:ajax` but it didn't solve the problem.

I tried to move the script inside the form that is being rendered, but it doesn't help

How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you updating part of the page?

Comment: yes. the part without the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nut, you'd like to re-execute it whenever the ajax request has been completed?

Move it into a function like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.spin.imageBasePath = '../images/spin1/';
    runSpinners();
});
function runSpinners() {
    jQuery('#spin1').spin();
    jQuery('#spin2').spin();
    jQuery('#spin3').spin();
}
```

This way you can reuse it in the `oncomplete` attribute of the `<p:commandButton>`.

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="runSpinners()" />
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/prime-showcase/ui/pprAjaxStatus.jsf) to execute it on complete of *every* ajax call, regardless of the button/link pressed:

```
<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete="runSpinners()" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not only this script. I also have a link to an additional script:
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/scripts/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js"></script>

that needs to be reinvoked

Comment: That plugin does nothing during onload. You can only activate it using `$(selector).selectbox();`. You'd like to re-execute that as well. Rename `runSpinners()` to `init()` or so and add the `selectbox()` calls in there.

Comment: I added your suggest, so now everything is in a function, but I get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'spin' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, you're using [`jQuery.noconflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). I'll update my answer ... Update: done :)

Answer (score 0):

Just write

$=jQuery;

After doing this you can enjoy the standard way of writing jQuery using $ sign...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.spin.imageBasePath = '../images/spin1/';
    runSpinners();
});
function runSpinners() {
    $('#spin1').spin();
    $('#spin2').spin();
}
```

Comment: dosen't this "steal" the $ variable from other libraries? I think the best way to do it is this: `(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)`. Read all the options here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries