# prime faces, replace a component with another one in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf, primefaces

I have done my homework https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsf+jquery

I'm using prime faces with SelectOneMenu http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

I'd like to integrate Chosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ because it has the ability to Allow Deselect on Single Selects.

What's the right way to integrate them i have used an aroach similar to [jquery with jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363085/jquery-with-jsf) with no succes.

But i'd like to use Chosen instead SelectOneMenu

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "deselect on single selects?"?

Look at the sample line 19:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

This allows a deselection. Be sure your converter returns null if the id is ""

```
    <h:outputText value="Pojo: " />  
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedPlayer1}" effect="fade" converter="player">  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
        <f:selectItems value="#{autoCompleteBean.players}" var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"/>  
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks, i know that i can put a value named none with value ""  but a more elegant way is not to add this value for eg to a long list loaded by database and leave it automanaged by component